# Averaging Gaussian Q function over Chi-squre distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, average, chi-squared, gaussian

Assume that we have
$$P(\alpha)  = Q(\sqrt{\alpha \rho})$$
where $Q(\alpha)$ is the Gaussian Q function defined as 
$$ Q(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_x^\infty \exp\{-\frac{u^2}{2}\} ~du$$

Can anyone kindly let me know the steps for averaging the Q function over a chi square distribution. In other words, to solve the following integral

$$P_{avg} = \int_0^\infty Q(\sqrt{\alpha \rho}) ~ \frac{1}{(2n-1)!} ~ \alpha^{2n-1} ~ e^{-\alpha} d\alpha$$

Appreciate your help.

Comment: The Gaussian Q function is defined as $$\frac{1}{\color{red}{\sqrt{2\pi}}} \int_x^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) du$$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the heads up. I changed that.